# Why dtype is different when converting to a category from an object or str?

Tags: python, pandas, categories

Why do I receive two different behaviours when converting a column to a category in pandas?

As an example, let say I create a dataframe with

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.22.0'
>>> np.__version__
'1.14.0'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nombre'], data=[1,2,3,4])
```

Now I convert my column to an object:

```
>>> df['nombre'] = df['nombre'].astype('object')
>>> print(df['nombre'].dtype)
object
```

The dtype is now object.

```
>>> df['nombre'] = df['nombre'].astype('category')
>>> print(df['nombre'].cat.categories.dtype.name)
int64
```

After converting to a category, the internal dtype is int64.

Let's start again with a new dataframe

```
>>> del df
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nombre'], data=[1,2,3,4])
```

This time, we convert the internal column to a 'str'

```
>>> df['nombre'] = df['nombre'].astype('str')
>>> print(df['nombre'].dtype)
object
```

The internal representation is an object. It makes sense since we converted to a 'str'.

```
>>> df['nombre'] = df['nombre'].astype('category')
>>> print(df['nombre'].cat.categories.dtype.name)
object
```

After converting to a category, the internal dtype is now object, which is different from the int64 that we received before?

So my question is the following, why do I receive two different behaviours when converting from an object dtype to a category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.astype(object)` doesn't convert numbers to strings. It converts numbers to corresponding Python objects (in your example, `numpy.int64` to a Python `int`).

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nombre'], data=[1,2,3,4])

type(df['nombre'][0])
Out[64]: numpy.int64


df['nombre'] = df['nombre'].astype('object')

type(df['nombre'][0])
Out[66]: int
```

But when you use `astype(str)`, it converts everything to strings. While doing that, it also converts the Series to an object Series, too. This is  because that's the only dtype that can hold strings.

```
df['nombre'] = df['nombre'].astype('str')

type(df['nombre'][0])
Out[69]: str
```

So this is just related to your input data. In the first one you pass ints, you get an integer array. In the second one you pass strings, you get an object array.

Also the term "the internal dtype" may not be appropriate here. This is the dtype of the Series that holds categories; not their codes. In both examples, `df['nombre'].cat.codes` is the internal representation and its dtype is `int8`.